# "OSError: Unable to create file" upon adding one character to h5 save name

Tags: python, keras, path, windows-10, h5py

**WORKS**:

```python
model.save_weights(base_path + name[:89] + '_weights.h5')
```

**DOESN'T**:

```python
model.save_weights(base_path + name[:90] + '_weights.h5')
```

---

Occurs when saving Keras model weights; error no matter what `name[89:]` is - but `name[:89]`'s all good to go. The only culprit in mind is savename length, but that's not reflected in the error - it and other details below.

Any remedy? Help's appreciated.

---

**OS**: Win 10-17134, 64-bit

```python
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '...', errno = 2,
error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)
```

```python
base_path = ("D:\\Desktop\\Database\\Deep Learning\\DL_code\\models_logs\\"  
           + "M22__DCSEResNet_MP1_lr5_13.5k_124x2_cnndp.5_sncnndp.1_stagedp.5"
           + "__cnnsedp.2_preodp.5_Nadam_1e-4__max.507\\")

name      = ("M22__DCSEResNet_MP1_lr5_13.5k_124x2_cnndp.5_sncnndp.1"
           + "_stagedp.5__cnnsedp.2_preodp.5_Nadam_1e-4__max.507_40vals")
name[:89] = ("M22__DCSEResNet_MP1_lr5_13.5k_124x2_cnndp.5_sncnndp.1"
           + "_stagedp.5__cnnsedp.2_preodp.5_Nadam")
```

```python
len(base_path + name      + '_weights.h5') = 279
len(base_path + name[:89] + '_weights.h5') = 259
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly the 2^8 limit, but probably your string has backslashes written as `\\` and so it breaks on 260, and not on 256.

P.S. silly me not seeing or you edited your question and added the path: your backslashes are indeed written as `\\`.

P.P.S. actually it's [260 chars limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)

Comment: If it were length-related wouldn't the error message reflect it? I'd be surprised to find something so basic not up-to-date in Python 3.7

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation